# PHP Form not validating

Tags: php, forms

Am trying to validate a form and the values of the form can only be inserted into the database if the security answer is correct.Yet the values gets inserted when a wrong answer is given.

```
if(empty($answer) && (!$answer == $sec_ans)) {
    echo "<div class='db_rp'>Error: You did not answer your security question</div>";
} else {

     $insert = "INSERT INTO laits SET 
     p_no = '{$new_pp}',
     r_number= '{$r_number}',
     memo = '{$memo}',
     user= '{$userid}',
     acc = '{$acc}'";

     if(!mysqli_query($conn, $insert)) {
     die('<div class="reply"> There was an error submtting your request ' . mysqli_error($conn)) . '</div>';
     }     
       else {
      header("location: tran_su.php"); 
       }
}
```

Comment: Is this the processing script that the form is being posted to?

Comment: You probably mean `if (empty($answer) || ($answer != $sec_ans))`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is requiring both conditions and should be only one as a minimum.

```
if(empty($answer) || ($answer != $sec_ans)) {
....
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (empty($answer) || ($answer != $sec_ans)) {
```

Comment: feel free to accept it as the correct answer or throw an upvote my way. Remember, when you're trying to access passed variables from a form you need `$_REQUEST[]` or `$_POST[]`.